# Get a headervalue of a websocket request using twisted and sockjs

Tags: python, twisted, sockjs

I have a sockjs server which is behind haproxy. Now i need to now a clients ip address but using `self.transport.getPeer()` i get the ip of my haproxy. Haproxy adds a X-Forward-For header to the request with the ip of the original client in it.

How can i get the original http request which has been sent to the server in my protocol?

```
class MyProtocol(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        # this next line only gives me the ip of my proxy
        ip = self.transport.getPeer()

class MyFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = MyProtocol

my_factory = MyFactory()
sockjs_factory = SockJSMultiFactory()
sockjs_factory.addFactory(my_factory, 'echo')

sockjs_service = internet.TCPServer(10000, sockjs_factory)

application = service.Application("frog32")
sockjs_service.setServiceParent(application)
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug that getPeer does not reflect the value of X-Forward(ed?)-For.  Rather than trying to get the raw bytes of the request (which are extremely complicated to properly parse, and if you do so incorrectly you may leave yourself open to peer address spoofing), perhaps you should file a feature request against the websocket server implementation.

Comment: i've found a ticket in the twisted trac which covers exactly this ussue http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5807